# I don't tell you or I won't tell you

Tags: speech

Is it correct to say I don't tell you or shall we use I won't tell you ?

Comment: They are certainly both sets of words.  You need to specify context.  What do you intend to say?

Comment: well I want to say that I am not going to tell a person, what he's asking me..

Comment: In that case, *I won't tell you* is the appropriate response.  *Won't* is short for *will not* —and you said it yourself (I am not going to tell… = I will not tell).

Comment: Thanks, that's my opinion too but a friend is used to saying I don't tell you, and I have no solid argument I just know that it should be I won't tell you and not I don't tell you :s

Comment: *I don't tell you* (*I do not tell you*) indicates something current and ongoing.  For example, if I normally do not talk to someone about what I do at work, I could say to them *I don't tell you about my work*.

Comment: Okay, so I don't tell you is correct too. My usage is that while in a conversation when I am asking my friend something, he will usually say I don't tell you.

Comment: Yes, but not in the context you referred to.  It is much more general, and will not really reference the specific question he asked.  If you ask him a question, and he replies *I don't tell you*, that doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that it is the response a generic question you refuse to answer. Please say if this assumption is false.

The usual reply is: "*I am not telling you"*, you can also say: *"I won't tell you"*.

*"I don't tell you"* it is not grammatically incorrect, but just doesn't sound English.